Why cant I modified the char array when passing it as an argument to the function and assigning it a new value?
void changeName(char* name) {
    //other action

    //strcpy(name, "String"); -- this working
    name = "Marcus"; //       -- this not working

}

int main() {
    char name[10] = "Jeremy";
    printf("%s\n", name);

    changeName(name); 
    //Aspected result: Marcus
    //Actual result: Jeremy

    printf("%s\n", name);
    return 0;
}

In the provided source code, when attempting to modify the char name[50] array from 'Jeremy' to 'Marcus' by passing it to a function, I encountered an issue with the assignment. I tried two methods:
Method 1:
strcpy(name, "String");

Method 2:
name = "Marcus";

But in somehow, The first method worked while the second did not. Why is this happening and how can i resolve this?

Parameters are local variables, but are initialised with the values in the function call. That means changing them only changes a local variable. In C, you generally need to pass a pointer to the value you want to change. In this case you change a local pointer, you need to pass in a pointer to the pointer you want to change.

In the example where you are assigning to the pointer, you are merely changing what the local char pointer name points to so that it points to a string literal "Marcus". This has no effect on the array in main.
In the example using strcpy, you modify the data the pointer points to. Notably, since you don't pass changeName any information on how large the char array is that the pointer points to, you have a potential buffer overflow bug.
This can be overcome using strncpy.
void changeName(char *name, size_t max) {
    strncpy(name, "String", max-1);
    name[max] = '\0';
}

Now we'd want to call this as follows. This cannot overflow name.
int main() {
    char name[10] = "Jeremy";

    printf("%s\n", name);
    changeName(name, sizeof(name) - 1); 
    printf("%s\n", name);

    return 0;
}


Generally, I think it is better to use snprintf with the %s specifier instead of using strncpy, as that function is guaranteed to always write a null character (unless the size of the buffer is zero). That way, you don't have to manually add one.

A  very salient point.

In my experience, it is more common to pass the size of the buffer to a function, instead of the maximum number of characters (without the null character). For example, the functions fgets and snprintf behave this way. This is safer, because if the programmer confuses the size of the buffer with the maximum number of characters when passing an argument to the function, then only one byte is wasted, whereas with your method, a buffer overflow will occur.

There are at least two fundamental misconceptions in

In the provided source code, when attempting to modify the char name[50] array from 'Jeremy' to 'Marcus' by passing it to a function:


You are not passing an array to the function.  You can be excused for thinking you were, as this is a common stumbling block for novice C programmers, but what you are actually passing is a pointer to the first element of the array.  In almost all contexts, definitely including as arguments to function calls, an lvalue of array type is automatically converted to a pointer to the first element of the array.  That your compiler does not call out a type mismatch with the parameter type of your function could have been a clue.

If you were passing the array itself then that would not serve your purpose.  In C, all arguments are passed by value.  No modification a C function can make to the value of one of its parameters is visible to the caller.  This is why your method 2 does not work as you want.


However, one of the things you can do is accept a pointer as a parameter and use its value to modify the data to which it points.  That is what your method 1 does.

For further reading about array to pointer decay: What is array-to-pointer conversion aka. decay?

Thanks for adding relevant knowledge, Problem solved.
